# Python get files from N days ago and before

Tags: python

I am trying to write a function that can find files from a certain date and before and delete them. I was playing around with fabric and I want to delete my old log files from my server. the folder has files in the following format:

```
['user-2015-10-16.log.gz', 'user-2015-10-19.log.gz', 'user-2015-10-22.log.gz', 'user-2015-10-25.log.gz', 'admin-2015-10-17.log.gz', 'admin-2015-10-20.log.gz', 'admin-2015-10-23.log.gz', 'requests.log', 'user-2015-10-17.log.gz', 'user-2015-10-20.log.gz', 'user-2015-10-23.log.gz', 'extra.log', 'admin-2015-10-18.log.gz', 'admin-2015-10-21.log.gz', 'admin-2015-10-24.log.gz', 'user-2015-10-18.log.gz', 'user-2015-10-21.log.gz', 'user-2015-10-24.log.gz', 'admin-2015-10-16.log.gz', 'admin-2015-10-19.log.gz', 'admin-2015-10-22.log.gz', 'admin-2015-10-25.log.gz']
```

What I want to do is keep files from today till 4 days back i.e. keep the ones from `25th, 24th, 23rd, 22nd` and delete the rest (keep extra.log and requests.log).

I tried this:

```
import datetime

days = 4

user = []
admin = []

for i in range(days):
    that_date = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=i)
    use = 'user-{}.log.gz'.format(that_date)
    adm = 'admin-{}.log.gz'.format(that_date)
    # user.append(user)
    # admin.append(admin)
    print user, adm
```

But realized embarrassingly late that this gives me the files I want to keep and not the ones I want to delete.

Any help will be greatly appreciated

Edit: if not already clear, the files are generated daily with the `user-(todays date)` format so cant hardcode anything.

Comment: are you just looking for name of the files that you want to delete?

Comment: yeah. Once I get those I can delete them.

Comment: ok I will post the answer below

Comment: Why don't save these file names in a `list` and do something like `set(all_files_list) - set(keep_files_list)`?

Comment: you're fine with how you append the names into that list, now you just need to iterate through your filenames and have somethign like `if filename not in user and filename not in admin:`

Comment: @RNar - Holy sh*t is was that easy!! Thanks a lot. I feel stupid now

Comment: oh the wonders of python

Comment: if you are on linux, rather than finding the files using the regexp, you can run the "find" command and take the output in a list and delete individual file for every element in list.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using [glob](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) with `user-*` and `admin-*` and then get the file creation times with [os.stat](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.stat)

NOT TESTED, but something like:

```
import glob
import os
import time

target=4*24*60*60   # 4 days in seconds

for fn in glob.glob('user-*')+glob.glob('admin-*'):
    if time.time()-os.path.getctime(fn)>target:
         # delete that file...
```

You need to change the working directory (or change the glob) to the target directory.